# Subtract with value in previous row to create a new column by subject

Tags: python, csv, pandas-groupby, rows

Using python and this data set https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yadatree/AL/main/AK4.csv I would like to create a new column for each subject, that starts with 0 (in the first row) and then subtracts the SCALE value from row 2 from row 1, then row 3 from row 2, row 4 from row 3, etc.

However, if this produces a negative value, then to give the output of 0.

Edit: Thank you for the response. That worked perfectly. The only remaining issue is that I'd like to start again with each subject (SUBJECT column).  The number of values for each subject is not fixed thus something that checks the SUBJECT column and then starts again from 0 would be ideal.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAkp6.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code.

Comment: you can use `.shift()` to move value from one row to previous row (as new columns - ie, `previous_value`) and you will have both values in one row and then you can simply substract two columns. And later  you can select rows with negative values and assing `0`

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: you could show (as text in question) minimal example and expected result. So we could simply copy example data and use it to test solutions.

Comment: you could try to use `groupby("SUBJECT")` and use `shift` in every group

Comment: or you could use `groupby` to put zero in first element in every group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.shift(1)` create new column with values moved from previous rows - and then you will have both values in the same row and you can substract columns.

And later you can selecte all negative results and assign zero

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'A': [1, 3, 2, 5, 1], 
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['previous'] = df['A'].shift(1)
df['result'] = df['A'] - df['previous']
print(df)

#df['result'] = df['A'] - df['A'].shift(1)
#print(df)

df.loc[ df['result'] < 0 , 'result'] = 0

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   A  previous  result
0  1       NaN     NaN
1  3       1.0     2.0
2  2       3.0    -1.0
3  5       2.0     3.0
4  1       5.0    -4.0

   A  previous  result
0  1       NaN     NaN
1  3       1.0     2.0
2  2       3.0     0.0
3  5       2.0     3.0
4  1       5.0     0.0
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you use `df['result'] = df['A'] - df['A'].shift(1)` then you get column `result` without creating column `previous`.

And if you use `.shift(1, fill_value=0)` then it will put `0` instead of `NaN` in first row.

---

**EDIT:**

You can use `groupy("SUBJECT")` to group by subject and later in every group you can put `0` in first row.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'S': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'A': [1, 3, 2, 1, 5, 1], 
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['result'] = df['A'] - df['A'].shift(1, fill_value=0)
print(df)

df.loc[ df['result'] < 0 , 'result'] = 0
print(df)

all_groups = df.groupby('S')
first_index = all_groups.apply(lambda grp: grp.index[0])
df.loc[first_index, 'result'] = 0

print(df)
```

Results:

```
   S  A  result
0  A  1       1
1  A  3       2
2  A  2      -1
3  B  1      -1
4  B  5       4
5  B  1      -4

   S  A  result
0  A  1       1
1  A  3       2
2  A  2       0
3  B  1       0
4  B  5       4
5  B  1       0

   S  A  result
0  A  1       0
1  A  3       2
2  A  2       0
3  B  1       0
4  B  5       4
5  B  1       0
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. That worked perfectly. The only remaining issue is that I'd like to start again with each subject (SUBJECT column).

Comment: I added code which use `groupby` to put `0` when start new subject.